# How can i find exact worked hours in a day and break hours in a day?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have break time and work time for the given day, how can i find exact worked hours in a day and break hours in a day?

Work time entry is like this

[image]

Previously I used to have only single scenario's like 2nd July, in that case I was converting the break time to hours and directly deducting them from work hours.

```
$secondsPerHour = 3600;

// Getting break entries
$breakTimeEntries = TimeEntries::select('start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'hour_type')
                               ->where('hour_type', 'break') 
                               ->orderBy('start_date')->get();

$breakDurationPerDayArray = array();
// Looping through all the break entries and getting the break entries for each day
foreach($breakTimeEntries as $breakTimeEntry) {
    $startDate = $breakTimeEntry->start_date;
    $breakStartTime = $breakTimeEntry->start_time;
    $breakEndTime = $breakTimeEntry->end_time;

    $breakHours = $breakEndTime - $breakStartTime;
    $breakHoursInSeconds = $breakHours/$secondsPerHour;

    // Adding the break entry for the day to array
    $breakTimePerDayArray[$startDate] = $breakHoursInSeconds;
}

// Getting work entries
$breakTimeEntries = TimeEntries::select('start_date', 'start_time', 'end_time', 'hour_type')
                               ->where('hour_type', 'work') 
                               ->orderBy('start_date')->get();

$workAndBreakHoursArray = array();                             
// Looping through all the work entries and getting the actual work entries for each day
foreach($breakTimeEntries as $breakTimeEntry) {                            
    $workStartTime = $workTimeEntry->start_time;
    $workEndTime = $workTimeEntry->end_time;

    $workHours = $workEndTime - $workStartTime;
    $workHoursInSeconds = $breakHours/$secondsPerHour;


    $startDate = $breakTimeEntry->start_date;

    // Checking wether the start date is in array
    if(in_array($startDate, $breakDurationPerDayArray)) {
        $breakHoursInSeconds = $breakDurationPerDayArray[$startDate];
        $actualWorkedHours = $workHoursInSeconds - $breakHoursInSeconds;
        //To get the worked hours in minutes
        $actualWorkedHoursInMins = $actualWorkedHours/$secondsPerHour;
        //To get the break hours in minutes
        $breakHoursInMin =  $breakHoursInSeconds/$secondsPerHour;
        $workAndBreakHoursArray[$startDate] = ['worked_hours' => $actualWorkedHoursInMins, 'break_hours' => $breakHoursInMin];
    } else {
        //To get the worked hours in minutes
        $workHoursInMins = $workHoursInSeconds/$secondsPerHour;
        $workAndBreakHoursArray[$startDate] = ['worked_hours' => $workHoursInMins, 'break_hours' => 0];
    }
}
```

I was out of ideas at this moment. Kindly anyone suggest best way to handle it.

Expected output is like this in hours

```
[
    [2018-07-02] => [Work => 8, Break =>1],
    [2018-07-03] => [Work => 8, Break =>1],
    [2018-07-04] => [Work => 8, Break =>1],
    [2018-07-05] => [Work => 3.5, Break =>0.5],
    [2018-07-06] => [Work => 4.5, Break =>0.5],
    [2018-07-09] => [Work => 3.5, Break =>0.5],
    [2018-07-10] => [Work => 4.5, Break =>0.5]
]
```

[Database Fiddle Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dpgYEgBLWESpzd28tXkJrj/1)

Comment: Not sure what you're asking? How to process the table?

Comment: So what is inside the variables? Unixtime? Hours? Seconds?

Comment: The problem is that your 3 cases have 3 different logic, so 1/ you use ONE logic for all the case so you know how to works with them or 2/ You make test (id end time > break start for example, etc.) to know which case you are and you do the logic according to the case. But the "logic" that could almost works is just to do, for each day : 1/ calculate each start - end period 2/ sum all work type period 3/ subtract the break period. But we have no information about how you get those data so hard to help

Comment: @WasteD I was converting them to seconds and then getting the difference

Comment: On line 5 you have to multiply not divide!

Comment: @MickaelLeger updated the sample code that I was using. Updated a little most of it is same.

Comment: @WasteD updated the sample code that I was using. Updated a little most of it is same.

Comment: Can you provide an SQLfiddle with some of your test data? I guess an SQL solution would be the best after all.

Comment: @Namoshek I prepared SQL but having problem with the SQL fiddle

Comment: They seem to have issues with their service. Maybe you can use [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/) instead? -- Edit: now it seems to work, all of a sudden. :)

Comment: @Namoshek updated fiddle link https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dpgYEgBLWESpzd28tXkJrj/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged Laravel, so I assume you're using it.
It has Carbon included, it's a great tool for everything related to time.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#Difference

Edit1: Here's an example, also assuming that you normalized entries:

```
$entries = [
    [
        'type'  => 'work',
        'start' => 1310198400,
        'end'   => 1310230800,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'break',
        'start' => 1310212800,
        'end'   => 1310216400,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'work',
        'start' => 1310284800,
        'end' => 1310299200,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'break',
        'start' => 1310299200,
        'end' => 1310302800,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'work',
        'start' => 1310302800,
        'end' => 1310317200,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'work',
        'start' => 1310371200,
        'end' => 1310385600,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'break',
        'start' => 1310384700,
        'end' => 1310387400,
    ],
    [
        'type'  => 'work',
        'start' => 1310387400,
        'end' => 1310403600,
    ]
];

$workEntries = collect();
$breakEntries = collect();

foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
    if ($entry['type'] == 'work')
        $workEntries->push($entry);

    else if ($entry['type'] == 'break')
        $breakEntries->push($entry);
}

/*
    For each work entry, check if any break entry overlaps.
*/
foreach ($workEntries as $workEntry)
{
    $workStart  = $workEntry['start'];
    $workEnd    = $workEntry['end'];

    foreach ($breakEntries as $breakEntry)
    {
        $breakStart         = $breakEntry['start'];
        $breakEnd           = $breakEntry['end'];
        $overlapDuration    = 0;

        if (!Carbon::createFromTimestamp($workStart)->isSameDay(Carbon::createFromTimestamp($breakStart)))
            continue;

        /*
            Check if work and break overlap

            Scenario 1:
                Break started mid-work

            Scenario 2:
                Break started before work
        */
        if (($breakStart >= $workStart) || ($breakStart < $workStart))
        {
            if ($breakStart >= $workStart)
                $overlapStart = $breakStart;

            else if ($breakStart < $workStart)
                $overlapStart = $workStart;

            /*
                Break ends before work ends (or simultaneously)
            */
            if ($breakEnd <= $workEnd)
                $overlapEnd = $breakEnd;

            /*
                Break ends after work ends
            */
            else
                $overlapEnd = $workEnd;

            /*
                Calculate overlap length
            */
            $overlapDuration = $overlapEnd - $overlapStart;
        }

        /*
            Actual time worked that day is time worked - breaks that overlap work periods.
            Get human-friendly date (day, month, year), display.
        */
        $workDuration = ($workEnd - $workStart - $overlapDuration)/3600;
        $date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($workStart)->toFormattedDateString();

        dump("Time worked on $date is $workDuration h.");
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
"Time worked on Jul 9, 2011 is 8 h."
"Time worked on Jul 10, 2011 is 4 h."
"Time worked on Jul 10, 2011 is 4 h."
"Time worked on Jul 11, 2011 is 3.75 h."
"Time worked on Jul 11, 2011 is 4.5 h."
```

I assume grouping that data for each day shouldn't cause much trouble :)

Edit2: I didn't notice you changed your question before I made a working example, so excuse that data is not displayed in the format you wanted. Again, making it fit your need should be an easy task.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged.

Comment: @Wokes getting overlap duration of 5 hours instead one if I check for 2011-07-09 first scenario

Comment: How come? Included example with the data prints 8h for Jul 9, 2011, which checks out: Work 8-12, break 12-13, work 13-17, so total 8h worked that day? Even printing out overlap durations shows 1 hour overlap on Jun 9th

Comment: @Wokes updated question to have more scenario that I could come across. I have tested with the solution that you gave I was getting 4 as worked hours and 5 has overlapped hours

Comment: In that case when you're separating all entries into work and break entries, you can check if day of start date is different than end date and split them into separate days.

Comment: @Wokes Here is the pastbin code that I have changed with your code https://pastebin.com/41UtH7GM

Comment: @Wokes updated db fiddle link also https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dpgYEgBLWESpzd28tXkJrj/1

Comment: @vvr02 And now you want him to fix the code so that you get a 100% working copy & paste solution, because the proof of concept isn't enough?

Comment: @MarioWerner As per checking with the solution it is giving the wrong value. So I have requested for it. I am not exactly looking for exact at least a path to move forward. Thanks

Comment: I already gave you the hint what to do to fix the problem, look at my previous comment.